# Non-trivial inequality

Tags: inequality

Equation (1) on page 7 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.7308v1.pdf claims that:
$$\frac{1}{t}\log \left(\frac{\log ((1+\epsilon)t)}{\omega} \right) \geq c \Rightarrow t \leq \frac{1}{c} \log \left( \frac{2\log \frac{1+\epsilon}{c\omega}}{\omega}\right)$$
The equation is convoluted because of the presence of a term like $\frac{1}{t} \log (\log t)$. Anybody knows how to prove this?